# Array of parameter in odeint

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve the differential equation with odeint. Here some constant parameters are fixed and some are in a list.

```
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator


    #equation of motion in the direction of x    ===== ### d^2x/dt^2 = q[Ex + dy/dt * Bz - dz/dt * By]/m 
    #equation of motion in the direction of y    ===== ### d^2y/dt^2 = q[Ey - dx/dt * Bz + dz/dt * Bx]/m 
    #equation of motion in the direction of z    ===== ### d^2z/dt^2 = q[Ez + dx/dt * By - dy/dt * Bx]/m



    m = 9.1 *(10)**(-31)    
    q = 1.6 *(10)**(-19)    



    #Electric field from FEMM
    with open("Elecric_field_x.txt") as f:
        flines = f.readlines()
        yy1 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]

    with open("Elecric_field_y.txt") as f:
        flines = f.readlines()
        yy2 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]

    with open("Elecric_field_z.txt") as f:
        flines = f.readlines()
        yy3 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]



    #Position x,y,z from FEMM
    with open("Electric_position_x.txt") as f:
        flines = f.readlines()
        y4 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]

    with open("Electric_position_y.txt") as f:
        flines = f.readlines()
        y5 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]

        with open("Electric_position_z.txt") as f:
            flines = f.readlines()
            y6 = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]

        #data sample from FEMM inside the text file


    yy1         yy2         yy3          y4         y5          y6


    2.677026732329115255e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.908106187718196067e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.639206109489374516e-17 2.677026732329115255e-01 3.908106187718196067e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
-2.677026732329115255e-01 3.278412218978749032e-17 3.908106187718196067e-01 -0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.031888048269389202e+01 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.452685819581209046e+02 5.000000000000000278e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.468819396416788133e-15 4.031888048269389202e+01 -1.452685819581209046e+02 3.061616997868383172e-18 5.000000000000000278e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00
-4.031888048269389202e+01 4.937638792833576266e-15 -1.452685819581209046e+02 -5.000000000000000278e-02 6.123233995736766344e-18 0.000000000000000000e+00
-2.020413445543617001e+02 -0.000000000000000000e+00 -2.380940300071312777e+03 1.000000000000000056e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
-1.237146429519632942e-14 -2.020413445543617001e+02 -2.380940300071312777e+03 6.123233995736766344e-18 1.000000000000000056e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.020413445543617001e+02 -2.474292859039265884e-14 -2.380940300071312777e+03 -1.000000000000000056e-01 1.224646799147353269e-17 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.549999999999999989e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000278e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.061616997868383172e-18 5.000000000000000278e-02 1.549999999999999989e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -5.000000000000000278e-02 6.123233995736766344e-18 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000056e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 6.123233995736766344e-18 1.000000000000000056e-01 1.549999999999999989e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.000000000000000056e-01 1.224646799147353269e-17 1.549999999999999989e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.099999999999999978e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.099999999999999978e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.099999999999999978e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000278e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.099999999999999978e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.061616997868383172e-18 5.000000000000000278e-02 3.099999999999999978e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -5.000000000000000278e-02 6.123233995736766344e-18 3.099999999999999978e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000056e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 3.099999999999999978e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 6.123233995736766344e-18 1.000000000000000056e-01 3.099999999999999978e-01
-0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.000000000000000056e-01 1.224646799147353269e-17 3.099999999999999978e-01


        #array for electric field components
    Ex1 = np.array(yy1, dtype=object) 
    Ey1 = np.array(yy2, dtype=object)
    Ez1 = np.array(yy3, dtype=object)



    #array for position
    x = np.array(y4, dtype=object) 
    y = np.array(y5, dtype=object)
    z = np.array(y6, dtype=object)




    def fE(x,y,z,yy1,yy2,yy3,y4,y5,y6):
        #array for electric field components
        Ex1 = np.array(yy1, dtype=object) 
        Ey1 = np.array(yy2, dtype=object)
        Ez1 = np.array(yy3, dtype=object)

        #array for position
        x = np.array(y4, dtype=object) 
        y = np.array(y5, dtype=object)
        z = np.array(y6, dtype=object)

        #linear interpolation of electric field
        ex = LinearNDInterpolator((x, y, z), Ex1)
        ey = LinearNDInterpolator((x, y, z), Ey1)
        ez = LinearNDInterpolator((x, y, z), Ez1)

        #array of new point
        x1 = np.linspace(0, 31, 100)
        y1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        z1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

        #creating array([x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],....) for new grids
        X = np.dstack((x1,y1,z1))
        points = np.array(X)

        #Electric field at new grids after linear interpolation
        fEx = ex(points)
        fEy = ey(points)
        fEz = ez(points)
        return fEx, fEy, fEz



    fEx, fEy, fEz = fE(x,y,z,yy1,yy2,yy3,y4,y5,y6)

    #Magnetic field 
    Bx = 0.1825 *(10)**(-4)         
    By = 0.00942 *(10)**(-4)        
    Bz = 0.46264 *(10)**(-4)      




    def trajectory(w, t, p):
        ###====Cartesian coordinate system=====#####
        #x = x1
        #x_prime = y1   #dx/dt
        #y = x2
        #y_prime = y2   #dy/dt
        #z = x3
        #z_prime = y3   #dz/dt

        x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = w
        q, m, fEx, fEy, fEz, Bx, By, Bz = p

        f = [y1, q*(fEx + y2 * Bz - y3 * By) / m, y2, q*(fEy - y1 * Bz + y3 * Bx) / m, y3, q*(fEz + y1 * By - y2 * Bx) / m] #with magnetic field
        return f


    #Initial conditions
    x1 = 0.0
    y1 = 0.0
    x2 = 0.0
    y2 = 0.0
    x3 = 0.006
    y3 = 68999.35

    #time
    t = np.linspace(0*(10)**(-9), 10.0*(10)**(-9), 100)
    p = [q, m, fEx, fEy, fEz, Bx, By, Bz]
    w0 = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]



    # Call the ODE solver.
    wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t, args=(p,))

    X = wsol[:,0]       #for x
    Y = wsol[:,2]       #for y
    Z = wsol[:,4]       #for z


    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(t,X,  color= 'b', label=('x'))
    ax.plot(t,Y, color= 'r', label=('y'))
    ax.plot(t,Z, color= 'c', label=('z'))
    ax.set_xlabel('Time(ns)')
    ax.set_ylabel('position(m)')
    plt.show()
```

But I  am getting following error: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "trajectory_cartesian.py", line 205, in 
        wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t, args=(p,))
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: You are trying to compute the motion of a charged particle in an EM field. If the fE arrays are a time dependent electrical field, you missed to also state the sample times and use interpolation to compute the field at a given time. Please confirm or correct these observations and adapt your code so that your error message is really the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### recent version of question - was XY problem, need E-field evaluation more dynamical

You are trying to pass a larger interpolated grid of values of the E field to the ODE function. This is not what you need. And also not possible, the parameter array was not intended for such a purpose. <sub>(That's why it was an XY problem, you want to solve X, use method Y and get a problem and then try troubleshooting Y without communicating X, but it turns out that method Y is not a good solution and you should use some other method Z)</sub>

The ODE function needs the value of the E-field at the current coordinates. Just make the interpolator a global object and use it in the ODE function, per the documentation of the interpolation function this should work. Using the given data points to fill the corners of a cube of sidelength 4, reading from a string instead of files,

```
griddata = """  597.8291    0.0         172.9540    -2.0   -2.0   -2.0
                561.7756    204.4696    172.9540    -2.0   -2.0   2.0
                457.9636    384.2771    172.9540    -2.0   2.0    -2.0
                298.9145    517.7352    172.9540    -2.0   2.0    2.0
                103.8119    588.7467    172.9540    2.0    -2.0   -2.0
                -103.8119   588.7467    172.9540    2.0    -2.0   2.0
                -298.9145   517.7352    172.9540    2.0    2.0    -2.0
                -457.9636   384.2771    172.9540    2.0    2.0    2.0""";

grid = [ [ float(cc) for cc in line.split()] for line in griddata.split("\n")];
grid = np.asarray(grid);

xyz_grid = grid[:,3:]   #   xyz_grid = np.array([y4, y5, y6]).T
E_grid = grid[:,:3]     #   E_grid = np.array([yy1, yy2, yy3]).T
E_field = LinearNDInterpolator( xyz_grid, E_grid )

def trajectory(w, t):
    x, vx, y, vy, z, vz = w
    Ex, Ey, Ez = E_field([x, y, z])[0] # returns list of arrays
    f = [ vx, q*(Ex + vy * Bz - vz * By) / m, 
          vy, q*(Ey + vz * Bx - vx * Bz) / m, 
          vz, q*(Ez + vx * By - vy * Bx) / m ]
    return f
```

Note that here all constants used in the function are global constants, so the call is

```
wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t)
```

this should only be changed if `q` and `m` are variable over different runs of the integration.

You probably should rescale the position and time variables so that both the coordinates and the velocities that `odeint` sees are in the magnitude range `0.1..10`. Otherwise the (default) tolerances might produce strange variations in the single components.

---

### old version of question, wrongly constructed parameter vector

The `lsode` wrapper `odeint` tries to cast your parameter list into an array. It expects that this list is a flat list of numbers. Your list contains other lists, which gives a heterogeneous structure that does not fit into a `numpy` array.

One has to question what the lists `fEx` etc. are meant to achieve, as the ODE function uses these parameters as if they were numbers.

---

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

m = 9.1e-31
q = 1.6e-19

Bx = 0.1825e-4       
By = 0.00942e-4  
Bz = 0.46264e-4   

fEt = [ 0, 2e-9, 4e-9, 6e-9, 8e-9, 10e-9]
fEx = [0.20507215, 0.20658776, 0.20810338, 0.20961899, 0.21113461, 0.21265022]
fEy = [0.17207596, 0.16972669, 0.16737742, 0.16502815, 0.16267888, 0.1603296]
fEz = [ 3.90810619e-01,  3.60677316e-01,  3.30544013e-01,  3.00410711e-01,   2.70277408e-01,  2.40144105e-01 ]

def trajectory(w, t, p):
    q, m = p  # not really necessary, global variables work here fine
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = w
    Ex, Ey, Ez = np.interp(t,fEt, fEx), np.interp(t,fEt, fEy), np.interp(t,fEt, fEz)
    f = [y1, q*(Ex + y2 * Bz - y3 * By) / m, y2, q*(Ey - y1 * Bz + y3 * Bx) / m, y3, q*(Ez + y1 * By - y2 * Bx) / m]
    return f

x1, y1 = 0.0, 0.0
x2, y2 = 0.0, 0.0
x3, y3 = 0.006, 68999.35

#time 
t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)*1e-9

p = [q, m]
w0 = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]

# Call the ODE solver.
wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t, args=(p,))
print wsol

x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = wsol.T

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x1,x2,x3,'r',label='charged particle trajectory')
ax.set_xlabel('$x_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$x_2$')
ax.set_zlabel('$x_3$')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: 3D plot of solution]

Comment: Actually, I have electric field in a text file (Ex,Ey,Ez) and position x,y,z. I got the electric field from FEMM software. After that I created array and did linear interpolation. fEx etc. are the data of electric field after linear interpolation.

Comment: Which means that `E` should be a function of `x,y,z`? Then the amount of data that you posted is by far insufficient and also without any context of where these values are actually taken. If you have FEM data you will need a structure or possibly library to read and interpret the data. For the immediate problem one could consider `E` constant, which the given values almost are.

Comment: I just uploaded my full script. Would you please check it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry , I am a beginner in programming, I am getting error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trajectory_test.py", line 150, in <module>
    wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t, args=p)
odepack.error: Extra arguments must be in a tuple

Comment: Yes, that was a wrong simplification that I did not transfer back. The old code in the bottom section should now work, the new version in the top section does not have parameters if you do not put them back in.

Comment: From which code? Python 2.7, and the complete script below produces the picture without error message. Obviously I can not test the fragment in top as I do not have the grid data. If you want to put something up, for a proof of concept a grid with only the 8 vertices of a single cube would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am expecting your help according to my new question!

Comment: I uploaded data, would you please check it!

Comment: The data is not sufficient, the grid points do not form a cube around the origin, the integration leaves the interpolation area. I just moved the points to the corners of the cube `[-2,2]^3` to get some result.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting output but I am expecting plot  from 0.006 to 0 in z direction but here is a plot from 0.006 to 0.0066. Is it due to the data or something else? If I want multiple line with different initial condition then how to plot ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can give some more conditions, you can get such a path via the boundary value problem solver `solve_bvp`.

Comment: Ok, I am still confused, If I have data for z coordinates from 0 to 10. When I used initial condition for z = 10. Then the trajectory should be from 10 to 0 at z coordinate (reverse direction). But I am getting trajectory from 10 to 20 at z. Why?

Comment: You have 6 initial conditions that select what path is being taken. Just changing `z` does not tell much. Do you have some kind of example solution that makes you say that the path should go to `z=0`?

Comment: I uploaded the data, here z coordinates starts from 0 to 0.309. When I use initial condition for z = 0.30 then the plot starts from 0.30. I don't know, what's the wrong? I am expecting the plot from 0.30 to 0. Thanks!

Comment: What are the other initial conditions? If the initial velocity in `z` direction is large and positive, it is not surprising that the value of `z` is growing.

Comment: all other initial conditions are exactly same which I mentioned above. OK, value of z is growing but it should be the trajectory from 0, am I right?

Comment: Yes, then at time `1e-8` you reach `z=0.300689185186`, which is close to `z0+dt*vz0=x3[0]+t[-1]*y3[0]=0.300689303506`, the path is completely dominated by the initial velocity. Why do you expect anything different?

Comment: OK. I am supplying voltage inside the region of z=0 to 0.3. So, I want to see the trajectory inside this  region.