# Python bvp solver with array like arguements

Tags: python, numpy, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a 4th order bvp using the bvp solver in Python. The differential equation is of the form given below :-

```
d4w(x)/dx4=t/(t-w(x))
```

with boundary conditions `w(0)=w(10)=w'(0)=w'(10)=0`  . If `t` in the differential equation is a simple constant, the code is simple and is given by

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

t=1

def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack([y[1], y[2], y[3], t/(t-y[0])])
def bc(ya, yb) :
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0], yb[1]])

xmesh = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.zeros((4, len(xmesh)))
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, xmesh, y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xmesh, sol.sol(xmesh)[0])
plt.legend()
```

But in my case, `t` is a pre-defined constant 1-D array. I am facing some issues in writing the code for this case. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So your equation really is `d4w(x)/dx4=t(x)/(t(x)-w(x))`? Did you try to use interpolation to get the correct `t` values?

Comment: The t values are pre-defined which I will be taking from a csv file.

Comment: But what do these values from the cvs file represent?

Comment: t represents the air gap between 2 beams. Actually the equation mentioned by me has no physical significance. The actual equation looks a bit different but has the form mentioned above.

Comment: The question is, is `t` constant for every beam/air gap and you want to integrate over each situation read from the file, or is `t` variable along the beam and the values in the file represent measurements at different places?

Comment: t is a variable along the beam but is known. t(x) is pre-defined and it represents measurements at different places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232335/discussion-between-anweshan-and-lutz-lehmann).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574843/solving-an-ode-y-f-x-with-numerical-values-of-f, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266330/how-to-insert-list-in-a-ode on how to use interpolation with discrete data. A more complicated case where a 3D field is interpolated is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115289/array-of-parameter-in-ode